I can't connect Gitea and Caddy via reverse proxy
Deployed Gitea in a local network (access via internal IP:port without problems). There is a working reverse proxy (Caddy). The task is to teach Gitea to work via Caddy. The problem is that all my attempts have failed.
`git.example.ru {
    reverse_proxy http://127.0.0.1:3000}`

This is a piece of Caddy config, other services (I have several deployed) work as they should, only Gitea does not start.
Next: the server part of the Gitea config:
`[server]
SSH_DOMAIN = localhost
DOMAIN = localhost
HTTP_PORT = 3000
ROOT_URL = http://localhost:3000/
APP_DATA_PATH = /var/snap/gitea/common/data
DISABLE_SSH = false
SSH_PORT = 22
LFS_START_SERVER = true
LFS_JWT_SECRET = mysecret
OFFLINE_MODE = false
`

Help me figure out what I'm doing wrong and why other services work through the caddy, but Gitea doesn't. I'll say it right away: in the Gitea config I changed localhost to both the domain name and the local IP, it had no effect.
I have repeatedly changed the Gitea configuration file in different ways. With any changes to the config, Gitea only works in the local network. I have not achieved proxying through Caddy in any case.
